# MySQL is only downloading in zip format. How to fix it? Or how to open?

Tags: mysql, windows, zip

Yesterday I went to download MySQL, and I managed to install it, when the download finished, I double-clicked and the program opened normally. I created an account just for testing, so I didn't save the password, so I deleted MySQL to create another account... However when I go to download, now only the option to download in Compressed (zipped) Folder format appears, and I have no idea how to open any type of download in that format, I've tried following the steps taught in the videos and I couldn't either.

Is there a way to fix this? Because yesterday MySQL was downloading normally (as in the image below) and I had no difficulty opening it.

[image]

But now the download is just like this (as in the image), and I can no longer open the program.

[image]

Note: I use the 64 bit version of Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're downloading MySQL community server from it's official page here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

If you are, then you can see in the page there are 3 blue buttons 
[image]

I assume that you are downloading from the "Other Downloads" section (no.2 in image).

Answer (score 0):

could you share the link to the source where you downloaded MySQL?

Usually you should be able to unzip the contents of any .zip file by right clicking the archive in a explorer and choosing extract (not sure what the exact buttons in Windows are called since I don't use it).

Maybe your file got corrupted while you downloaded it (connection issues), have you tried re-downloading it?

I've just searched for the download and started it from the official website
(https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-community-8.0.32.0.msi). This starts the download of an .msi file in my case. Can you confirm that this still starts the download of a .zip file?